# ConstraintSet>>applyTo Setting the Alpha Of a TextView to 1f

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, constraints, alpha

I'm working on an Android app (Target API 28, min API 22) written in Kotlin using Android Studio.

I have a ConstraintLayout with a number of Views added to it. Among them is a simple TextView. I want the TextView to initialize with an alpha of `0f` (invisible) and then later on (via animation) change its value to `1f` to make them visible. I got the animation working, but the initial alpha did not appear to be having any effect. I eventually traced the issue to the `ConstraintSet>>applyTo(...)` method. The snippet below shows that `ConstraintSet>>applyTo(...)` sets the alpha of the TextView back to `1f` even though I explicitly set it to `0f`.

```
val textView = TextView(context)
textView.id = View.generateViewId()
textView.text = "Hello World"
addView(textView)

val set ConstraintSet()
set.constrainHeight(textView.id, WRAP_CONTENT)
set.constrainWidth(textView.id, WRAP_CONTENT)
set.connect(textView.id, TOP, PARENT_ID, TOP)
set.connect(textView.id, START, PARENT_ID, START)
set.connect(textView.id, END, PARENT_ID, END)
set.connect(textView.id, BOTTOM, PARENT_ID, BOTTOM)
println("1. textView=${textView.alpha}")
textView.alpha = 0f
println("2. textView=${textView.alpha}")
set.applyTo(this)
println("3. textView=${textView.alpha}")
textView.alpha = 0f
println("4. textView=${textView.alpha}")
```

When I run my app, the below output is generated in the Run window:

```
I/System.out: 1. textView=1.0
              2. textView=0.0
              3. textView=1.0
              4. textView=0.0
```

By setting the alpha of the TextView after the ConstraintSet>>applyTo(...) call, I achieve an alpha of `0f`.

My question is...why? Why is ConstraintSet changing properties of the views it's constraining that have (seemingly) nothing to do with constraints? Are there other properties that ConstraintSet sets when it is applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah it's pretty counter intuitive. `ConstraintSet` creates an extension of actual `LayoutParams` before applying them.

This extension is `android.support.constraint.Constraints.LayoutParams`, at this moment (decompiled from `constraint-layout:1.1.3`) it stores the following (with default values):

```
public static class LayoutParams extends android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams {
    public float alpha = 1.0F;
    public boolean applyElevation = false;
    public float elevation = 0.0F;
    public float rotation = 0.0F;
    public float rotationX = 0.0F;
    public float rotationY = 0.0F;
    public float scaleX = 1.0F;
    public float scaleY = 1.0F;
    public float transformPivotX = 0.0F;
    public float transformPivotY = 0.0F;
    public float translationX = 0.0F;
    public float translationY = 0.0F;
    public float translationZ = 0.0F;

    //... rest of class
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell ConstraintSet not to use it's own LayoutParams (ie. to use the LayoutParams of the Views themselves)? Or is the solution to just hold off on setting LayoutParams properties until after applying the ConstraintSet. The latter makes it difficult when making custom Views where you want to preconfigure those properties.

Comment: @DavidA sadly constraintSet is not that flexible... You can `clone(ConstraintLayout constraintLayout)` current layout params of your `ConstraintLayout` before modifying `ConstraintSet`, this will cause a bit of overhead but unless you have very complex layout it should be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.